# What program can I use to open the *.dmp file to read the lost data from the form?

Tags: windows, forms, webforms, dump, coredump

I was filling out a very lengthly form in Firefox, but accidentally clicked 'Back' and lost my filled form data. I installed the 'Progress Hack' program for Windows 10 and created a dump file of the firefox process. And now I can't find a program to read this file to read the lost data from the form in it. Tell me, please, which program it can be done with?

Comment: I assume Windbg.  That said, I would start by downloading Strings from Sysinternals and dump all the strings in the dump to a text file. `strings.exe firef.dmp > all.txt` If you know roughly what you are looking for in terms of keywords, you might find enough that way to reconstruct your lost text.